# incrementar uma variável index durante uma atribuição vetorizada no pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Bom, eu tenho um dataframe assim.

| index | Mobile Phone |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | +XXXXXXXXXXXXX |
| 2 | +XXXXXXXXXXXXX |
| 3 | +XXXXXXXXXXXXX |

e eu preciso adicionar nele mais uma coluna, que ira guardar os dados que representam um tipo de contador, esse contador possui um formato especifico, parecido com o de um relógio, assim: "Prefix - 001 - 001".
Onde o primeiro "001" será incrementado em 1 quando o segundo "001" chegar ao valor 250, sendo que esse segundo contador será incrementado de acordo com o index do dataframe, e quando ele chega a 250 o seu valor deve retornar para o inicial "001", como mostrado nessa tabela.

| index | Count Identifier | Mobile Phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Prefix - 001 - 001 | +XXXXXXXXXXXXX |
| 2 | Prefix - 001 - 002 | +XXXXXXXXXXXXX |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 250 | Prefix - 001 - 250 | +XXXXXXXXXXXXX |
| 251 | Prefix - 002 - 001 | +XXXXXXXXXXXXX |

Para adicionar a nova coluna é simples, o problema que estou enfrentando é para preenche-la igual na tabela, não estou conseguindo de forma alguma incrementar os dois contadores.
Com a minha experiencia em java, a primeira coisa que pensei foi usar o ++i, porem isso não existe em python, e não consegui achar nada equivalente, visto que o ++i alem de incrementar tbem retorna o valor, que é justamente o que eu preciso e facilitaria muito o trabalho se eu pudesse incrementar e ao mesmo tempo retornar o valor, mas o python não permite fazer atribuições dentro de expressões e as atribuições não retornam valor, então minha primeira tentativa como segue abaixo não rola.

```
df['Count Identifier'] = 'Prefix' + ' - ' + ('{:0>3}'.format(i1) if i2 < 250 else ++i1) + ' - ' + (++i2 if i2 <= 250 else i2/=i2)
```

Depois eu tentei utilizar uma função que seria chamada durante a atribuição na coluna, porem tbem não funciona, pois a atribuição é vetorizada, assim sendo, ela so chama a função uma unica vez, o que faz com que os contadores so sejam incrementados uma vez.

```
df['Count Identifier'] = 'Prefix' + ' - ' + ('{:0>3}'.format(i1) if i2 < 250 else update_index_1()) + ' - ' + (update_index_2() if i2 <= 250 else reset_index_2())
```

Tbem pensei em Pré preencher a coluna com valor padrão "Prefix - 001 - 001" e depois ir alterando os contadores usando o valor da linha anterior, porem não sei como fazer para pegar o valor da linha anterior, e tbem não tenho certeza se isso seria o suficiente pra resolver esse problema, se alguém tiver uma luz de como dar um passo adiante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É uma questão matemática não precisando de expressões condicionais ou substituições de strings. Veja seus requisitos:

> ...O primeiro "001" será incrementado em 1 quando o segundo "001" chegar
> ao valor 250, sendo que esse segundo contador será incrementado de
> acordo com o index do dataframe, e quando ele chega a 250 o seu valor
> deve retornar para o inicial "001"...

- O primeiro valor, esse pode ser calculado, a cada linha, com a [divisão inteira //](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions) de cada elemento do índice por 251.
- Quanto ao segundo valor, esse pode ser calculado a cada linha com o [operador resto %](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions) da divisão de cada elemento índice por 250.

Definindo `df` como um conjunto de dados para esse exercício mental:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Mobile Phone":["+XXXXXXXXXXXXX"]*1000})
#       Mobile Phone    
#0     +XXXXXXXXXXXXX  
#1     +XXXXXXXXXXXXX  
#2     +XXXXXXXXXXXXX  
#3     +XXXXXXXXXXXXX 
#...        ...
#999   +XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Adequando o [índice do DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.index.html) ao exemplo da pergunta, o incrementando em uma unidade:

```
>>> df.index += 1
#       Mobile Phone    
#1     +XXXXXXXXXXXXX  
#2     +XXXXXXXXXXXXX  
#3     +XXXXXXXXXXXXX  
#4     +XXXXXXXXXXXXX 
#...        ...
#1000   +XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Calculando e formatando o primeiro número fazendo as devidas compensações por conta do índice incrementado. Em seguida alterando o tipo dos dados de numérico para string com [pandas.Series.astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) e caso necessário o preenchendo com zeros a esquerda com [pandas.Series.str.zfill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html)

```
>>> (df.index // 251 + 1).astype(str).str.zfill(3)
#001
#001
#001
#001
...
#004
```

Calculando e formatando o segundo número fazendo as devidas compensações.

```
>>> ((df.index - 1) % 250 + 1).astype(str).str.zfill(3) 
#001
#002
#003
#004
...
#250
```

Então o calculo de `'Count Identifier'` de forma vetorizada será:

```
>>> df['Count Identifier'] = (
...    "Prefix - " + 
...    (df.index // 251 + 1).astype(str).str.zfill(3) +
...    " - " +
...    ((df.index - 1) % 250 + 1).astype(str).str.zfill(3)  
...)
>>> df
#       Mobile Phone    Count Identifier
#1     +XXXXXXXXXXXXX  Prefix - 001 - 001
#2     +XXXXXXXXXXXXX  Prefix - 001 - 002
#3     +XXXXXXXXXXXXX  Prefix - 001 - 003
#4     +XXXXXXXXXXXXX  Prefix - 001 - 004 
#...        ...               ...
#1000  +XXXXXXXXXXXXX  Prefix - 004 - 250
```

Juntando tudo num único fragmento:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Mobile Phone":["+XXXXXXXXXXXXX"]*1000})
df.index += 1

df['Count Identifier'] = (
    "Prefix - " + 
    (df.index // 251 + 1).astype(str).str.zfill(3) +
    " - " +
    ((df.index - 1) % 250 + 1).astype(str).str.zfill(3)    
)

print(df.to_string())   #Força a impressão de todas as linhas do dataframe.
```

<sup>Veja o resultado no [Replit](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/modcounter#main.py)</sup>

Comment: Perfeito, so tive que alterar alguma coisinha pois vou usar com o índice iniciando em zero mesmo, espero chegar a esse nível de percepção, no final era algo "simples" que eu estava complicando mais do que deveria. Muito Obrigado.